How to shift operation to the Secondary name node?
I have a three-node HDFS cluster with a Name Node/Datanode, a Secondary Name Node/Datanode, and a Datanode.
My primary Name Node burned in a fire, but the other two are just fine. How do I shift to the secondary name node and recover the data?

hdfs name node -backup

try this command it may resolve your problem and check if the secondary name nodes are correctly configured :
   hdfs getconf -secondaryNameNodes
   hdfs getconf -backupNodes

https://github.com/naver/hadoop/blob/master/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/site/markdown/HDFSCommands.md#namenode
